# How to configure Entity Framework in a separate project?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, architecture

I have an ASP.NET MVC application `EducationalCenter` with the following structure of projects:

[image]

`DbContext` file is `EducationalCenterContext.cs` in the `Data` project and looks as follows:

```
public sealed class EducationalCenterContext: DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }

    public EducationalCenterContext( DbContextOptions<EducationalCenterContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
        Database.EnsureCreated();
    }
}
```

And in `Startup.cs` file, the dbContext configured as follows in `ConfigureService()`:

```
services.AddDbContext<EducationalCenterContext>
                (options => options.UseSqlServer("Server=localhost;Database=EducationalCenterDb;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"));
```

This is my working version to which I came by fixing errors when try to add-migration. However it seems awful to me that my web app has project reference to the `Data` project.

What was my first idea:

In `appsettings.json` I created this section :

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection":  "Server=localhost;Database=EducationalCenterDb;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true" 
}
```

Then I created `AppSettings` class in the `Common` project:

```
public class AppSettings
{
    public string ConnectionString { get; set; }
}
```

Then I try to pass `ConnectionString` in DAL via DI:

```
services.Configure<AppSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("ConnectionStrings"));
```

And created `EducationalDbContext.cs`:

```
public sealed class EducationalCenterContext: DbContext
{
    private readonly string _connectionString;

    public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }

    public EducationalCenterContext( IOptions<AppSettings>, DbContextOptions<EducationalCenterContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
        _connectionString = app.Value.ConnectionString;
        Database.EnsureCreated();
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(_connectionString);
    }
}
```

But when I try to `add-migration` via PM Console, I ran into this error:

> Could not load assembly 'EducationalCenter.Data'. Ensure it is referenced by the startup project 'EducationalCenter'

Then I added project reference and ran into the next error:

> Unable to create an object of type 'EducationalCenterContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728

Then I added `services.AddDbContext<>` in `Startup.cs` and came to the working version which I mentioned above.

So...

1. Is it normal that my web app has reference to the data access project?
2. Is it possible to configure EF in the `Data` project and ensure normal separation between DAL, BLL and web app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Putting the context and configuration in a separate project is fine.

You got the first error because "Education Center" was set as start up project but did not have reference to data project.

The second error is because the migration builder needs some connection information in the data project to resolve the connection (to compare EF state and database state) to determine what changes are needed.

First add reference in your data project to:

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design
```

Then add a context factory in your data project that migration console command will discover:

```
internal class MyContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<MyContext>
{
    public MyContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
    {
        var dbContextBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyContext>();
        var connString = "myconnection string";
        dbContextBuilder.UseSqlServer(connString);
        return new MyContext(dbContextBuilder.Options);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, your solution works! However, my EducationalCenter (web app) need to have reference to data project. Is it normal?

Comment: Yes, if you WebApp wants to communicate with EducationalCenter.Data project (which it clearly would) then it will need a reference to that project.